# How do I convert this label.text to an Integer so that the integer does not return nil?

Tags: swift, types, option-type

I'm trying to pass a number from a label to a timer.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    seconds = Int(timerTimeSetting.text!)! //Here is my problem line
    if let task = timerTask {
        timerTaskName.text = task.task
    }

    if let timerTimeLeft = timerTime {
        timerTimeSetting.text = timerTimeLeft.time
    }

    self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))

}
```

I get a "found nil" error. Below is how I initialize the seconds variable.

```
var seconds: Int = 0
```

Comment: Can you show me a result of print(timerTimeSetting?.text). Int class has fail-able initializer that accept string value and try to change it to Int. Getting nil back mean by it failed the operation. So if the label text has format like 00:00:00, then you may want to split those using "components(":")" and cover to int accordingly.

Comment: I did this and it prints Optional("10")...I can safely unwrap but I still get nil

Comment: so I ended up successfully converting to an integer like so                          
    let timeLeft: Int? = Int(timerTimeSetting.text!)

Comment: I'm not sure how to write code in comments

Comment: That is because Int(String) return Int? type. Did you check the value inside timeLeft was not nil? If worked then all good!

Comment: I figured it out but thank you